# R Shiny publishing - SSL certificate errors

Tags: r, ssl-certificate, shiny

I am trying to publish a shiny app but keep getting the following error:

(note that I've replaced my user/token/secret).

I've been following instructions from [Shinyapps.io](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson7/) and [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html), and I have set up an account at both shinyapps.io and lately even tried RStudio Connect. I always end up at the same SSL certicate error. I'm on a corporate machine behind their firewall. Is there a way I can get my shiny published?

```
> setAccountInfo("user","token", "secret")
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Timing stopped at: 0.03 0 0.7
```